# How to implement onOptionsItemSelected for Sub-Menu Items?

Tags: android, menuitem, submenu

I have encountered a situation where I need to implement onOptionsItemSelected listener for the subMenu of an item. The menu xml file looks as below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">

         <menu>

            <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
                  android:title="Create New" />
            <item android:id="@+id/open"
                  android:title="Open" />
        </menu>
    </item>


    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:title="New Game"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>


    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:title="Help" 
          android:showAsAction="always"/>


</menu>
```

As I'm able to implement option listener for items, where as I want to know how to implement action listener for the **action_settings** that have sub-menu items. 
 Kindly help me regarding this I have gogled but I was unable to find exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, worked when I implemented a switch for each item selected. It was not necessary implement a listener method.

```
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:

                break;

            case 2:

                break;

            case 3:

                break;  

            default:
                break;
            }       

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onClick and do this:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.action_settings:
            ....
            break;
          }
   }
```

Comment: I want to know how to implement listeners for items inside the action_settings...after clicking action_setting then a menu popups showing items, I want to know how to implement listeners for these items inside action_settings item.

Comment: if you don't mine, can you provide me a full code for what I'm looking?